# Bitbake does not work when toaster tool is setup

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded, build-system

I have followed the steps from here https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/toaster-manual/toaster-manual.html#toaster-manual-intro to set up the toaster tool on my project.

Toaster was successfully started but when i do a bitbake for my project it give the below error and stops.

Below are the steps that I followed.

```
$ cd <project>
$ pip3 install -r bitbake/toaster-requirements.txt
## dependencies got installed
$ source oe-init-build-env
$ source toaster start webport=8400
```

It gave the success output

```
The system will start.
Check if toaster can listen on localhost:8000
OK
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, bldcontrol, contenttypes, orm, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Starting webserver...
Toaster development webserver started at http://localhost:8000

You can now run 'bitbake <target>' on the command line and monitor your build in Toaster.
You can also use a Toaster project to configure and run a build.

Successful start.
```

Then do bitbake

```
bitbake <project>
```

This fails/stops with below message.

```
Timeout while waiting for a reply from the bitbake server (60s)
```

Bitbake works fine if I stop the toaster.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error above suggests a network problem. That said, consider filing a bug report. If you wanted to make it on-topic here, you'd have to extract and provide a [mcve] (posted inline, not linked).